# Scattering parameters of a phase shifter

Tags: phase-shift, waveguide

I connected a phase shifter to a VNA and measured S11 and S21. Upon setting the angle (phase) to a 100 degrees and measuring the phase of S11 I obtained the following graph, whereas theoretically S11=S22=0. I am having difficulties explaining this result and would appreciate some help.

As can be seen from the graph, in this waveguide TE10 is active between 6.6 GHz and approx. 13GHz. It appears to be oscillating between -180 deg. and +180 deg., yet with variations (certain angles seem to be far less than 180 deg. for instance).

As said, I'd appreciate your help interpreting these results.

[image]

Comment: SA (Spectrum Analyzer), are you sure you're not using a **Network Analyzer**? Waveguides cannot oscillate (they're passive components), maybe you mean **resonate**? Include a schematic/drawing of your setup. Did you calibrate your setup and how? Why measure phase of S11 instead of S12? You really need to explain better what you're doing and how/why.

Comment: 1. We can't read your mind. What phase shifter (model number or datasheet)? What SA (model number or datasheet)? 2. S11 and S22 are never actually 0.

Comment: Also, a magnitude plot to compare the phase plot to would help---hint: when the magnitude gets close to 0, how does noise affect the measured phase?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Yes, of course, my mistake -- VNA. It was calibrated using the standard kit, viz. short, open, load.

Comment: @ThePhoton the model is HP X885A

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a magnitude plot. Only the following measurements - phase of S11 and of S21 (without any angle shift), S11 and S21 (with angle shift of 0 deg.), S11 and S21 (with angle shift of 100 deg.).

Comment: I managed analyzing the results for S21, but I am having difficulties interpreting the results for S11

Comment: How is the RF signal fed into the waveguide system?

Comment: phase wrap anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no waveguide guy, but I've spent a bit of time fussing with VNAs.

The information I found about the X885A phase shifter was from the January 1955(!) [Hewlett-Packard Journal](http://www.hpl.hp.com/hpjournal/pdfs/IssuePDFs/1955-01.pdf).

First, it appears the X885A phase shifter is designed for operation between 8.2 and 12.4 GHz (excuse me, 8.2 to 12.4 kilo-megacycles). You should not expect it to be well matched outside this band.

Second, the typical VSWR is given as about 1.2 in the operating band. This means an \$S_{11}\$ or \$S_{22}\$ magnitude of about 0.1.

Third, your phase plot looks like what happens when no signal is received by the VNA and you're basically looking at the phase of the receiver noise.

My advice is to re-measure the device and be sure to record the S-parameter magnitudes as well as the phase, so you can know whether you are actually measuring a valid signal.

I don't know how VNA measurements on waveguide work, but it may be that the feed  from the VNA output to the waveguide is simply not very efficient, or the actual VSWR is much better than the 1.2 spec, so that the reflection is not enough to achieve a low-noise measurement. Under this theory, the reason you're seeing a reasonable phase measurement below 7 GHz is because of very high \$S_{11}\$ in this frequency range.

Comment: Unfortunately I am no longer able to perform any further measurements. What I wished to verify here was why the phase of S11 was not zero between 8.2 and 12.4GHz. Are you claiming it's merely the phase of the receiver noise and for any more profound evaluation the magnitude would have to be measured as well?

Comment: @peripatein, You should not expect the phase of the reflection to be 0. Ideally, the magnitude should be 0. But there will be deviations from this and they might be in any direction on the Smith chart, resulting in any phase from 0 to \$2\pi\$. As for whether you're measuring actual reflections from the DUT or just receiver noise, yes I think you need to measure magnitude as well as phase to work that out.